# Confluent 4.1.0 KSQL Issue (Cannot override property 'bootstrap.servers')

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am using confluent 4.0.1

I am starting the KSQL CLI with the following command.

```
./bin/ksql --config-file etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties -- http://127.0.0.1:9195
```

When I try to query the streams or create new streams I am getting following error.

```
ksql> select * from TLS_FAX_MSG_CONTROL_STREAM;
Cannot override property 'bootstrap.servers'
ksql>
```

I have verified all the config and it looks good.

We never get such error in 0.5 version.

Comment: You've presented a number of text screens as images. [Please read this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) to see why that is not ideal, and replace them with their text equivalents. It looks like you started to do that in a comment - please move that to the post, format it appropriately, and do the same for the other images. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for advising the correct way of posting questions. I highly appreciate your effort. I hope its ok now.

Comment: You're welcome - do the other two screens need pasting also? I wonder if people might ask to see the code or config that produces this error.

Comment: How are you running Confluent Platform? Using `confluent start`? What command & options are you using to launch KSQL?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt got the answer from Apurva Mehta in GitHub. I will post the answer here for others. Thanks a ton for looking into issue.
You guys Rocks :)

Comment: @halfer yes it was required I added the same in answer. :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt 

./bin/ksql --config-file etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties -- http://127.0.0.1:9195

Comment: @ZamirArif: if that material (e.g. the start command) is part of the context that readers need, please move it to your question. Don't forget other readers need that information, and they will want to get it from the question, not from answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the servers bootstrap.properties for the CLI. [Please have a look at this document](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/cli-config.html) to learn about which configurations you can override in the CLI.

I recommend that you don't specify a config file to the CLI at all unless you really need to override one of the overridable properties.

This is what is happening here.

I start the CLI using the following command.

```
./bin/ksql --config-file etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties -- http://127.0.0.1:9195
```

It fails to query the broker complaining about the issue as mentioned in the question.

When I remove the `--config-file` from the command it works.

After login when I check the properties as shown below:

```
ksql> SHOW PROPERTIES;
Property                                         | Value  
...
...
...
ksql.schema.registry.url                         | http://127.0.0.1:9193 
listeners                                        | http://127.0.0.1:9195 
bootstrap.servers                                | 127.0.0.1:9192 
...
...
...
```

I guess when you the properties file with one of the above configurations. It tries to override it and fails.